# Dynamic Page loading using <ui:include> is initializing beans only once

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm loading page dynamically using ajax and primefaces Layout. Here are my pages.

index.xhtml

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit position="north">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south">
                <h1>Footer</h1>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="west">
                <h:form>

                    <p:menu>
                        <p:menuitem value="Page1" action="#{navigationBean.method('page1')}"
                                    ajax="true" update=":main-content"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="Page2" action="#{navigationBean.method('page2')}"
                                    ajax="true" update=":main-content"/>
                    </p:menu>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center" >

                <h:panelGroup id="main-content">
                    <ui:include src="#{navigationBean.page}.xhtml" />
                </h:panelGroup>

            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
```

NavigationBean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class NavigationBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value="page1")
    private String page;

public String getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(String page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public void method(String page){
        this.page = page;
    }
}
```

page1.xhtml

```
<h:outputText value="#{page1Bean.text}"/>
```

page2.xhtml

```
<h:outputText value="#{page2Bean.text}"/>
```

Page1Bean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Page1Bean {

    private String text;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        System.out.println("\nPage1Bean @PostConstruct");;
    }

    public Page1Bean() {
        text = "Page 1 BEan Text Variable";
        System.out.println("Page1Bean Constructor");
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

Page2Bean.java is similar to Page1Bean.java.
The code is working fine and loading pages dynamically and using ajax.
But the problem is **@PostConstruct and Constructors of Page1Bean and Page2Bean are called only once.**
I mean those methods are called when the page is loaded for first time.
But they are not called again when the page is loaded second time.
So if anyone had done it before or seen it before Please help me how to handle this situation.

**EDIT :** I've tried @Viewscope on Page1Bean and Page2Bean based on Luiggi Mendoza's idea,but Still no luck.
It works **GOOD for @REQUESTSCOPE** (thanks for that Luiggi Mendoza), but what if in future **i get some @SESSIONSCOPE beans??**

Comment: If you want to instantiate a bean every time your page load then that bean should be a request scoped.`Viewscope` is like a `sessionscoped` bean for that particular view.So, If you want new instance everytime page loads I guess request scope is the only option.

Comment: @SrinivasR `@RequestScoped` will be created on every request on the same page (including ajax requests). It seems that `@ViewScoped` will work for this since the bean will be created every time you access the page: first access, second access, access from a different tab, refreshing the page, etc.

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your question: *what if in future i get some @SESSIONSCOPE beans*. You can inject `@SessionScoped` managed beans inside `@RequestScoped` as shown in your code, so there will be no problem at all. Also, please try with a more elaborated example than just navigating from one page to another to really see the difference between `@RequestScoped` and `@ViewScoped`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the scope from `@SessionScoped` to a narrower scope like `@ViewScoped` or `@RequestScoped`. For this case, it seems that `@ViewScoped` serves your purpose.

BalusC explains the details of every JSF managed bean scope in his blog article [Communication in JSF 2: Managed Bean Scopes](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes).